# React native facebook login sdk deprecated

Tags: android, ios, react-native, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

[image]

Read more about it here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/19/introducing-facebook-platform-sdk-version-9/ Do i now have to implement `native modules` using the `native` `android` and `ios` `sdk` in my `react native` project. The above post does not give a solution to deprecated react native `facebook` login. I don't see any community package for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not archived yet. I have implemented it several months ago and it still works fine.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk